# Can't call the methods using confluence objects:- "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, confluence

When I tried to create login to the atlassian-confluence, When I tried to create the object by passing user name(email_id) and API token password, I am getting error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

I tried to hit the url using curl with the same user email id and password, I got the valid response as below:-

```
curl -v https://XXXXXXX.atlassian.net --user arun.kumar@something.com:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
* Rebuilt URL to: https://projectcyclone.atlassian.net/
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to XXXXXXXX.atlassian.net (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Atlassian Network (easy handle 0x7f90af808400)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: XXXXXXXXXXX.atlassian.net
> Authorization: Basic YXJ1bi5rdW1hckB2aW9vaC5jb206VmYzYkRZUlRTR1I5ZHB6T3BqV3NENDNG
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
```

But when I tried to create the object using my credentials, I can't call methods using that object.

```
   confluence = Confluence(    
            url="https://XXXXXX.atlassian.net",
            username="arun.kumar@something.com",
            password="xxxxxxxxx")
   try:
       confluence.get_page_by_title("My space","MyPage")
   except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Full traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/k.arunkumar/confluence/py/confluence.py", line 26, in
>   myconfluence confluence.get_page_by_title("MY Space","My Page") File
>   "/Users/k.arunkumar/confluence/lib/python3.6/site-packages/atlassian/confluence.py",
>   line 128, in get_page_by_title return (self.get(url, params=params) or
>   {}).get('results')[0] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not
>   subscriptable

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of your error?

Comment: Hi @ItamarMushkin, I am just getting ```'NoneType' object is not subscriptable``` error only. Is there any way that I can get the full trace errors. Sorry I am new to coding.

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure, that if you'll just do the command instead of the "try/except" clause you'll see the whole traceback... try it

Comment: ItamarMushkin - I managed to get the error using ```raceback.format_exc()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/k.arunkumar/confluence/py/confluence.py", line 26, in myconfluence
    confluence.get_page_by_title("MY Space","My Page")
  File "/Users/k.arunkumar/confluence/lib/python3.6/site-packages/atlassian/confluence.py", line 128, in get_page_by_title
    return (self.get(url, params=params) or {}).get('results')[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable ```

Comment: Please add your error to the question, not as a comment. To learn more, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much. I have updated the error  in the question section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `(self.get(url, params=params) or {}).get('results')[0]` allows for this situation:

- `self.get(url, params=params)` returns `None`, because `url` happens to be a key that does not exist
- In which case, `(self.get(url, params=params) or {})` returns `{}` (an empty `dict`)
- This empty dict does not have the `results` key (or any other key), so `{}.get('results')` is `None`...
- and trying to call `None[0]` causes your error.

Comment: Thank you very much Itamar Mushkin, the issue seems with the parameters  MY Space and MY Page as I was able to call other methods using that object.